# Operator norm of the inverse

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inverse

If I made no mistake, one can calculate the operator norm of the inverse of any given (invertible) operator $A: V\rightarrow V$ via:

\begin{align}\|A^{-1}\| & = \sup\left\{\frac{\|A^{-1}b\|}{\|b\|} : b\neq 0\right\} \\
& \qquad \left\downarrow A\text{ is a bijection }V\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow V\setminus\{0\}\right. \\
& = \sup\left\{\frac{\|A^{-1}Ab\|}{\|Ab\|} : b\neq 0\right\} \\
& = \sup\left\{\frac{\|b\|}{\|Ab\|} : b\neq 0\right\} \\
& = \frac{1}{\inf\left\{\frac{\|Ab\|}{\|b\|} : b\neq 0\right\}}\end{align}

Is there a name for the expression $\inf\left\{\frac{\|Ab\|}{\|b\|} : b\neq 0\right\}$ which is similar to the operator norm but with replacing $\sup$ with $\inf$?

**Note:** Above I assumed $\inf\left\{\frac{\|Ab\|}{\|b\|} : b\neq 0\right\} > 0$ which is always the case if $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you could start by playing with vector $p$-norms with negative $p$ values? So $||x||_{-p}=((\sum_i |1/x_i|^p)^{1/p})^{-1}$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes. This is the smallest singular value, as a direct consequence of the min-max theorem for singular values.

For extra information you may want to consult: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value (section basic properties),  or for example Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen and Bau, see pages 94-95, if you prefer a real book.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1230748)

Comment: The question is: Is there a name for the expression $\inf \{\frac{ \| Ab\|}{\|b\|}\mid b \neq 0 \}$? The answer is yes, it is called the smallest singular value.