# Upper bound on infinity norm of inverse of a positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Consider a positive definite matrix, $A$, and the following quantity:
\begin{align}
\|A^{-1}\|_\infty
\end{align}
Are there any upper bounds on the above normed term?

---

EDIT: The bound should be in terms of $A$, such as the elements or eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: You might be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755561/operator-norm-of-the-inverse You can use this because all matrix norms are equivalent... But I guess this will not give you the upper bound you are looking for...

Comment: An upper bound in terms of what?

Comment: If all elements of $A$  are bounded from below by some $\varepsilon>0$, then one can show that $||Ax||_{∞} \geq \varepsilon ||x||_{∞}$ hence $||A^{-1}||_{∞}\geq  \varepsilon$

Comment: Hi @MOMO, that seems wrong: first, I think you meant to conclude $||A^{-1}||_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$. Second, the first bound needs more care: even when the entries of $A$ and $x$ are non-negative, one still needs to account for the dimension-dependent gap in the unit balls. Assuming $A_{i,j} > \epsilon, x_j \geq 0$, we have $||A x||_{\infty} \geq \frac{1}{N} \epsilon ||x||_{\infty}$. These forgo p.d. of $A$.